# Getting portfolio names and existing orders using Interactive Brokers IBPy

Tags: python, interactive-brokers, ibpy

I've been experimenting with IBPy for a while; however, the two following things have been eluding me:

a) How does one the name of the actual portfolios that positions belong to? I know how to find positions, their costs, values etc. (using message.UpdatePortfolio), but out trading simulation will likely have many portfolios and it helps to know which portfolio each position belongs to. Is it even possible to send information to IB in multiple portfolios?

b) How does one find out the existing orders using IBPy? So when I run the code, I want it to display all positions, along with their order types and limits (e.g. if its a limit order for AAPL, I want to find the limit price etc.)

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

a) As far as I know, IB API has no concept of 'Portfolio'. You probably need to keep a list of orders put in for which portfolio and then resolve the order data supplied by IB against your portfolio vs order data.

b) IB does keep track of the client (i.e. your client that is calling the API code - normally defaulted to 0) that has put in the orders.

If you want to know what orders are open that were input via your client then: client.reqOpenOrders();

If you want to know all open orders i.e. orders put in via your client plus other clients or TWS, then: client.reqAllOpenOrders();